# Can I set a breakpoint on a changing value?

Tags: php, xdebug, phpstorm

I want to pause execution only when the value in a variable changes to a specific value. I am using PHPStorm and Xdebug. Can anyone tell me how to do this?

Comment: See [documentation](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Using+the+PhpStorm+Debugger#UsingthePhpStormDebugger-Breakpoints), there are conditional, one time and disabled after another breakpoint is reached breakpoints. You can also force php to log message to console instead of suspending when breakpoint reached.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Put a breakpoint and then right click on it (on the red bullet). Select edit and you can enter a condition.

Comment: :p Duh. Indeed I can. Now that I know it, it's completely obvious. Thanks, linepogl!

Comment: What syntax do you use? Say you want `$k == 5`. I enter that and it does not work.

Comment: Can't believe I've not figured this out before! Thanks a bunch!

Comment: The syntax outlined by @greg is correct and works.

Answer (score 1):

Install breakpoints after press it right. In the window that appears, enter the condition for which you want to stop the debugger. With zend debugger it's work.

Comment: +1 for the right answer, but I've got to give it to answer @linepogl for answering first. Welcome to Stackoverflow!

Answer (score 0):

BTW it seems not to work alsways as expected.

"Stops but condition isnt true ... hmmm. strange
With the same condition other brakpoints works as expected."
http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-21071